# Waiting for npm run-script build to complete before re-starting the server with nodejs/nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am serving my react app with a small express server.

When the server is running, I start a setInterval passing a function to check if my local copy is at the same point my remote repository is.

To check if my local and remote are equal, I am using the child_process from node to execute two git commands.

```
git rev-parse @ 
git ls-remote
```

If the hashes are not equal I will call a module to execute the build command.

Until this point, everything works perfectly. If my remote branch changes, my local code will get updated.

The problem is when I am building the app...

I update my code and when I am finished I will call the module that is responsible to re-build my app.

I am using exec from child_process from node and my function is returning a new promise.

That is the body of my function:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try{
        exec(`npm run-script build`, async ( err, stdout, stderr ) => {
            if ( err ) {
                console.log( `Error trying to create build version: ${ err }` );
                resolve(false)
            }if ( stdout ){
                console.log( `Building...: ${ stdout }` );
                resolve(true)    
            }
            else{
                console.log( `Error trying to build application: ${ stderr }` );
                resolve(false)
            }
        });
    }catch( error ){
        console.log('Command Error: ', error)
        console.log( `Error trying to execute command build: ${ error }` );
        reject(false)
    }
})
```

Where the build function is called I have:

```
await buildApp()
```

But it isn't waiting for the build to be completed or when the build gets called, I get an error 
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

That is the log

```
9 verbose lifecycle @private/project@1.0.1~build: CWD: F:\Working\project\client\Frontend
```

10 silly lifecycle @private/project@1.0.1~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle @private/project@1.0.1~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @private/project@1.0.1~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: @private/project@1.0.1 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid @private/project@1.0.1
15 verbose cwd F:\Working\project\client\Frontend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run-script" "build"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1